# Find a good drawing for the edges of any two component of $G-S$ that do not cross

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry

A *drawing* of a graph $G$ on the plane $P$ is a representation of $G$, where vertices are distinct points in $P$, and edges are Jordan arcs in the plane joining the points corresponding to their end vertices.

My first question is:

**Question 1** Let $S$ is a separate set of a graph $G$ for $|S|\le 2$. Is there a  good drawing such that any edges belonging to  two different component of $G-S$ do not cross each other?

> If we do not impose any restrictions on the drawing of graph,
> obviously it can be done. The schematic diagram is as follows.[image] Thus we consider here drawing of graph
> is a **good drawing**. Good drawing means that no edge crosses itself,
> no two edges cross more than once, and no two edges incident with the
> same vertex cross each other.

Furthermore we limit general graphs to $k$-plane graphs, especially $1$-plane graphs. (A drawing of a graph is a $1$-planar drawing if each edge is crossed at most once. A graph is $1$-planar if it has a $1$-planar drawing. A graph together with a 1-planar drawing is a $1$-plane graph.)

So my another question will become as follows:

**Question 2** Let $G$ be a $1$-plane graph and $S$ be a separate set for $|S|\le 2$. Is there a $1$-plane drawing such that any edges belonging to  two different component of $G-S$ do not cross each other?

As can be seen from some examples, the above proposition feels positive.
But I don’t know how to strictly prove.

---

**Edit**
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: In your example drawing at the bottom of the post, what is the set $S$? Does "separate set" mean the same as *separating set*? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_separator

Comment: You are right. Sorry, I drew an extra edge between the two components, causing your misunderstanding. Once my computer is around I will modify it.

Comment: Thanks, it is clearer now: $S$ is the two blue vertices?

Comment: Yes.  The two blue vertices are form the  separating set $S$.

Comment: Do you already have the answer for $\lvert S \rvert = 1$? Presumably that is the easier case.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not clear about the case for $|S|=1$. But for maximal 1-plane graphs, it is correct for arbitrary separating set $S$ of $G$, even $|S|> 2$. It can be proven.